# launch eclipse,and an error occurs

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

environment:
Ubuntu 9.10
Eclipse eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-linux-gtk

When I login the ubuntu,and run the eclipse, it works. but when I changed to root user and then launch eclipse,there is an error occurs:

> (eclipse:5632): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer
>   instance
>
> (eclipse:5632): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data:
>   assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen:
>   assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must
>   always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must
>   always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_screen_get_display: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_display_get_pointer: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must
>   always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_screen_get_n_monitors: assertion
>   `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must
>   always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
>
> (eclipse:5632): Gdk-CRITICAL **: get_monitor: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN
>   (screen)' failed Segmentation fault

But when I login in Ubuntu as root, and run eclipse, it is ok. I changed to another non-root user,there is an error too.

How to deal with this problem.  I am looking forward to your reply.  thanks.

Comment: Why would you run eclipse as root?  Development with root sounds dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never use your root account as a normal user. Use Ubuntu's "sudo" command instead.

The error, by the way, is you are logged in as your user and you are using root from a terminal, so root doesn't find a screen.

You should never use Eclipse as root either, why would you want to develop with your root account? This is crazy talk!!

1. First rule about GNU/Linux-Unix is you do not login with your root account for daily use.
2. Second rule about GNU/Linux-Unix is you do not login with your root account for daily use.
3. Third rule about GNU/Linux-Unix is RTFM.

Hope this helps. Don't use root.

Comment: it works.
(1)ln -s /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java /usr/bin/java
(2)sudo ./eclipse

i use sudo to launch eclipse because i want to listen to 53 port in my project which is below 1024.

thanks for your reply.

Comment: Right. Anyway, I'd recommend as VonC says, redirecting port 53 to say 8053. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use Eclipse as you (and not root), would be to try and redirect the port 53 you want to listen to to (for instance) 8053 [through **rinetd**](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/rinetd-redirects-tcp-connections-from-one-ip-address-and-port-to-another.html).
(see this [SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/84360/regular-user-using-ports-below-1024/84368#84368)).

The idea remains: avoid running anything as root ;)